# C strtok is not tokenizing empty token value

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok

I have a small program that uses `strtok` as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="1,2,,3,4,5";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,",");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My output is coming as:

```
Splitting string "1,2,,3,4,5" into tokens:
1
2
3
4
5
```

But I need to get an empty value as an empty string when I encounter consecutive delimiters as `,,` for example in this case.
I.e. I need the output to be as:
Splitting string "1,2,,3,4,5" into tokens:

```
1
2

3
4
5
```

Any remedy?

Comment: `"1,2,,3,4,5"` ---> `"1,2, ,3,4,5"` No simple ways to do so. You must check addresses returned by strtok and check if difference == 1.

Comment: use `strpbrk` as suggested by @FredLarson's link

Comment: This is correct behavior. Just check `strlen(pch)` and ignore it if it's zero.

Answer (score 3):

That's how `strtok()` behave. Quoting the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter. [...]

You can make use of `strchr()` or `strpbrk()` to find out each occurrences of the delimiter and count separately.